# Mastering Geo Locators in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geolocation

We just moved from 10.0 to 10.2 and woke up to the wonderful news that all our geolocators are broke and need to be recreated. Most were made in 9.3. This is fine, but the locator building process has changed significantly and to be honest I've inherited the GIS coordinator/admin role with very little knowledge of ESRI products.

I'm trying to build a locator or composite locator that will check for the address, street name, and then if it can't find anything show the block range where this address should exist. I've got the first two created and working, but I cannot get a locator to do block ranges. The fields line up properly and we have block ranges in our streets layer. What am I missing? I tried the dual range type locator to no avail.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this a custom locator style that you are working with or are you using one of the standard styles? What do you mean by it's not working? Does it not generate? Or does it generate, but doesn't actually geocode, etc?

Comment: The locator works, all of them work I've created and all are standard styles, but neither the street name or dual range locators generate a block range when an address isn't found.

Comment: <Begin Snark>Sorry to say it but welcome to the world of ESRI and the ever moving undocumented target<End Snark>

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know you could do that with the standard locator styles in 9.3.1. My approach would be to use a customized style, that returns the entire line geometry. That's not really a trivial task though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the locators have to be built from scratch.  Here are some resources which should help you in this process:

- http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002500000013000000
- http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00250000000v000000

In your specific case, we would need more information, but from what is given this should be the style you need.

- US Address—Dual Ranges

Comment: Jeremy, the old locators cannot be rebuilt. There is some sort of bug in 10.2 that breaks the older locators permanently. The give an error that they need to be repaired before rebuilding, and when you do click ok it runs and runs with no result.

Also, I've used the dual ranges, but it is not giving me a block nearby where the address should be.

Comment: @Jack-sumMaster-null Sorry rebuilt was not the correct term, I meant built from scratch.  I will edit the Answer.